# Validate a form in view with Symfony 2.0

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, symfony

I work with symfony 2.0 and I have a view (test.html.php) that contains a

```
form:
<form action="" method="post" rel="">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test" />
    <input name="myinput" type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Go" />
</form>
```

This form sends the value of myinput to testAction in ActionController (and it works) but I wanna add a validation function with jQuery and/or AJAX to validate the myinput value before sending it to the controller and I don't know where to integrate it exactly

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hook up your javascript validation function to submit event of the form. Use google, there is billion of examples on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 validations for client side validation.